# insert into php database "No Database Selected" Error

Tags: php, mysql, foreach, insert

I have a foreach code which gathers data of each employee id from other tables (e.g. evaluation, attendance).

now I want to push these newly gathered data into a new table called `dss` so here is my code

```
$servername = "localhost";
$dbname = "ems_db";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername,  $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "INSERT INTO dss (emp_name, average, date)
VALUES ($name, $average, $date)";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
```

and this is the result that I get

```
Error: INSERT INTO dss (emp_name, average, date) VALUES (Francis Ajax, 65, 2016-03-17)
No database selected
Error: INSERT INTO dss (emp_name, average, date) VALUES (Horus Skye, 66, 2016-03-17)
No database selected
Error: INSERT INTO dss (emp_name, average, date) VALUES (Lotus Po, 68, 2016-03-17)
No database selected
```

can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong and how to fix it? :(

found new error

```
 Error: INSERT INTO dss (emp_name, average, date) VALUES (Lotus Po, 68, 2016-03-17)
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Po, 68, 2016-03-17)' at line 2
```

I think its because the varchar needs the `" "` or `' '` but since my values came from variables I don't really know how to fix it..

Comment: I'm surprised you're connecting at all. The options for a new connection is `$servername, $username, $password, $database` in that order. Unless you've removed it for posting here, you're missing it.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm still new at this. What if my db in localhost doesn't have username and password? I removed it because I know I don't have it yet... :(

Comment: It always has a username, but may not have a password, which is a VERY BIG security hole. You can use dummy holders for now. `$username = ''; $password = '';`

Comment: Database doesn't has username and password. Root is default username and ""  is dafault password. You can also set your own username and password in phpmyadmin.

Comment: thank you :) I have new error tho I'll edit the question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your connection syntax is incorrect

Try this:

```
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $db_name);
// By default $username = 'root' and $password = ''
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: hi! I think this solved it but now it has new error `Error: INSERT INTO dss (emp_name, average, date) VALUES (Lotus Po, 68, 2016-03-17)
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Po, 68, 2016-03-17)' at line 2`

Comment: I think its because I need the varchar to have `" "`?

Comment: Yeah, you need to put each of the values within quotes ""

Comment: is there a way to do it even tho my values are variables?

Comment: nevermind all I had to do was put `'$name'` thank you for all the help :)

Answer (score 2):

[http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php](http://mysqli%20construct%20manual)

The syntax for constructing a new mysqli object is:

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
```

Therefore you should provide the username and password. These may be blanks or defaults.

Answer (score 0):

use this for database connection and try :

$dbserver = 'localhost';

$dbusername = 'your user name' ;

$dbpassword = ' your password  ';

$dbname = 'ems_db';

if(!mysql_connect($dbserver, $dbusername, $dbpassword))

{

die("Database Connection Failed" . mysql_error());

}

if(!mysql_select_db($dbname))

{

die("Database Selection Failed" . mysql_error());

}